# Alternative to UNION similar queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, microsoft-query

I have a query similar to the following where I need to UNION a result from the numbers 5 to 15.  Instead of writing 10 of these queries is there a better way to do this?  I need to plug this into EXCEL as Microsoft query for a spreadsheet.

```
select SUM(rd.rd_net_cost)
from hqpm..receiver_d rd
inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id
inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id
where RES_NUM = 5
UNION
select SUM(rd.rd_net_cost)
from hqpm..receiver_d rd
inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id
inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id
where RES_NUM = 6
UNION
select SUM(rd.rd_net_cost)
from hqpm..receiver_d rd
inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id
inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id
where RES_NUM = 7
```

Comment: @DaleK sorry I actually need the different numbers in WHERE modified the query.

Comment: Well I already showed you that `WHERE Fee.amount_paid in (5,6,7)`

Comment: Jeepers, every time you edit the question you totally change it... please ensure you have a clear question before you post!

Comment: @DaleK  Actually I my select is a SUM() otherwise this woulda worked do you know how to do the same thing for a SUM() select?  See edit.  But that is a good solution otherwise.

Comment: Please add sample data and desired results so we are sure we know what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide sample data using DDL and DML statements, and the desired output from that sample data. It's ridiculous trying to hit a moving target. This is not supposed to be a shooting gallery. Add the specific details so that someone can try to help instead of wasting both your time and ours.

Comment: Why does simple group by not work? e.g., `select RES_NUM, SUM(rd.rd_net_cost)
from hqpm..receiver_d rd
inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id
inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id WHERE RES_NUM BETWEEN 5 AND 15 GROUP BY RES_NUM`

Comment: @seanb yes I think that would work I would hide the res_num column in excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was posted in comments - but the OP thought it would work.

Original comment was asking why a simple `group by` would not work? e.g.,

```
select RES_NUM, SUM(rd.rd_net_cost) 
  from hqpm..receiver_d rd 
  inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id 
  inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id 
WHERE RES_NUM BETWEEN 5 AND 15 
GROUP BY RES_NUM
```

@Bakalolo's further comment is to say that it appears to work, but that he would hide the res_num column in Excel - but there's actually no need for it to be included in the output. You can just select the SUM component e.g.,

```
select SUM(rd.rd_net_cost) AS Cost_Total
  from hqpm..receiver_d rd 
  inner join hqpm..re r on r.rcv_id = rd.rcv_id 
  inner join hqpm..store_ta st on st.store_id = r.st_id 
WHERE RES_NUM BETWEEN 5 AND 15 
GROUP BY RES_NUM
```

(Also note that I named the output field as Cost_Total).

Finally note that in the original question, it was using `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`. UNION removes duplicates - so that if (say) RES_NUM 5 totalled to 30, and RES_NUM 6 also totalled to 30, you'd only get one row out.

I assumed this is an error in the original question's approach. If not, we'll need to add an additional 'group by' (e.g., use the original answer as a CTE/source table, and group by the result).

Comment: Although one wonders how that can be meaningful given the final results won't be able to be matched to a `RES_NUM` - but thats a problem for OP.

Comment: I don't disagree. But that appears to be what they are asking.